# moving files to different folders from 1

Tags: command, xcopy

I have 200,000 files I want to send to different folders based on key words in the file name

in English   if a file name has (shtf or prepper or prepping or survival) in the name send(move) it to folder shtf

```
        if a file has (cookbook or gluten or recipe) move to food folder
                       *cookbook* *GLUTEN* *RECIPE*
```

example
(file name)
more shtf tips.epub       move to folder shtf

ifshtfbeready.epub        move to folder shtf

oldworldcookbook.epub     move to folder food

i'm old retired ibmer       small basic   sas   dos commands or ????

Comment: Are you looking for files in one folder? Or are your moving files from many different source folders?  If the latter then how to you prevent name conflicts if they are all moved to the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash command, you may be able to adapt it into dos etc. I'm posting this because others may it useful as well.

```
find . | grep -E "(cookbook|gluten|recipe)" | while read name; do mv $name directory; done;
```

Where `directory` is the name of the directory you want to move the file. You can replace `.` with whatever starting directory you want, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard in the source filename list and use a directory as the target to move multiple files with one command.

```
move c:\dir1\*cookbook*.* c:\food
move c:\dir1\*gluten*.* c:\food
```

Comment: about what i did tks

Comment: about what i did tks                                                                                                           tricky (4 me )was blanks                                                                                                  move c:\epub\*stack" "overflow*.epub                                                                              to avoid getting   coppersmith if searching for copper

Comment: You will not be able to distinguish between `cook` and `cookbook` with such a simple tool.  You could add quotes to allow spaces in the arguments to the move command. `move "path with spaces\* copper *" "target path"`